# Data Import -Live To Development

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

How do I import data from live to Development using scripts?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Script the data](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=56E5B1C5-BF17-42E0-A410-371A838E570A&displaylang=en) from the live server and run the scripts on the development server.

You might need to use something like the [Microsoft SQL Server Database Publishing Wizard](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=56E5B1C5-BF17-42E0-A410-371A838E570A&displaylang=en).  I've used this before to copy data between databases.

Comment: Do I set a specific property to true to import the data?  I can see the the objects are being imported but not the data..

Comment: @Hari Gillala - I updated the link to refer to the Database Publishing Wizard.  It has facilities to generate scripts for both schema and data.